# Use string as a placeholder for color

Tags: css, sass

I have SASS set up in a project and I need to change the color variables based on a value from the database. Since I don't want to carry the SASS files in the production environment, I want to write some SASS code looking like:

```
$custombrand-primary: "$custombrand-primary" !default;

.header 
{
  background-color: $custombrand-primary;  
}
```

...which generates a CSS looking like:

```
.header 
{
  background-color: "$custombrand-primary";  
}
```

Then, I will replace the "placeholders" from the generated CSS file on the server side.

Still, the SASS compiler won't let me use strings as parameters for mixins or gradients. How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: why does it have to be a string? Why not just http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7226e0472a244296527b9855411a92fc? And what do you mean it won't let you use strings?

Comment: Because on the production environment, I will have only the generated CSS file, the SASS files won't be there. So I need to generate the CSS with placeholders as strings

Comment: Why does the placeholder have to be a string? I assume you're using some backend language to replace the string `"$custombrand-primary"`, I don't see why it wouldn't be able to replace `custombrand_primary` without any quotes

Comment: why cant you rename the variable as something else as apart from $custombrand-primary because both are same...and try without quotes it should work

Comment: If I use anything else than a HEX code (with or without quotes), I get this kind of errors:   argument '$color' of 'adjust-hue($color, $degrees)' must be a color

Comment: @LucianVilcea you can't do that. `adjust-hue` is a SASS function, meaning sass will attempt to compile it to a color. The best thing you could do is replace it from the database, *then* compile the sass

Comment: If you can ignore IE, you could consider using CSS variables. https://www.sitepoint.com/css-variables-can-preprocessors-cant/ Otherwise, I agree that you should get the values from the database first, then compile the Sass.